# Impersonate the user EMAIL ID using Google Oauth2 Credentials ‘Service Account’

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am trying to create Google calendar events using Google Api OAuth service Account from PHP GAE.

I need the correct **Session ID** or the **user EMail ID** in the Calendar events field  **‘created by’**. 
This is possible well in **Google Apps Script(GAS)**, it creates the events with the correct session ID.

But, I want the same to be done in **PHP GAE(Google App Engine)**. So, I tried to impersonate the user ID as follows:[Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)

My aim is to insert the correct user ID of any end user automatically as like in **GAS(Google Apps Script)**. **I don't want any default credentials to be set in the field ‘created by’..**

Using the **PHP client library** i tried to impersonate a user in Calendar API.I didn't get any complete sample for Calendar API.So, I tried the Drive API documentation  [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object), this sample seems to be working fine, Using other domain user also

Using Calendar API  I wrote the below example.

```
 <?php
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php');
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php');
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php');

    use google\appengine\api\users\User;
    use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

    $user = UserService::getCurrentUser();
    $userEmail=$user->getEmail();

    $client_email = '34234242424-qssjf8kg1kk42dnjdvd2ndrk7rou44@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $private_key = file_get_contents('key.p12');
    $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key
    );
    $credentials->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    }
    $service =new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2015-09-26T10:00:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2015-09-26T10:00:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('abc@group.calendar.google.com', $event);
```

**It’s working well when i check this email, i got the correct service account credentials.
But when i used different email ID,  i got this below error**

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }'' in /base/data/home/apps/s~production/1.3874/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:363 Stack trace: #0 /base/data/home/apps/s~production/1.387/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(314): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) #1 /base/data/home/apps/s~ei-html-production/1.3874/final.php(34): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion() #2 {main} thrown in /base/data/home/apps/s~production/1.38742/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php on line 363
```

Plz help me what i did wrong.Why the issue happens, when I used diff email ID, my end user who'll create cal events, could be any GMAIL or Google based domain ID.

So, plz help with at least a sample part...

**Reference links:**

[How do I Insert Google Calendar Event using Google Api 3 for any user in the domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247644/how-do-i-insert-google-calendar-event-using-google-api-3-for-any-user-in-the-dom)

[How to create a Google Calendar event without a reminder / How to get Service Accounts to impersonate users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887070/how-to-create-a-google-calendar-event-without-a-reminder-how-to-get-service-ac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only impersonate users on a google apps domain where you have the necessary permission for (search for 'domain wide delegation'). You've got that covered.

Once you're authorized for impersonation you have to recreate a fresh Google Client for each user you impersonate. You'll only receive an access_token you can use for this very user. If you just change the email address once you're authorized it will not work.

Comment: thanks Konqi, I tried it's working in same domain user. But i want impersonate different domain user. Is it possible?

Comment: You can only impersonate users of a domain when the domain has authorized your app for that with domain wide delegation. If you want to impersonate a different user of the domain you are authorized for domain wide delegation you must create a new google client for every user. Usually if you require authorization to do something as a user you would not go about it with domain wide delegation but with plain OAuth 2.0 asking for offline access for that resource.

Comment: thanks Konqi for your reply, My API CONSOLE in DOMAIN1.COM, nd end user is in DOMAIN2.COM. using test@domain1.com working fine, but using test2@domain2.com not working getting error. Plz help me how to solve this.

Comment: domain1 and domain2 must be google apps domains. You need to log into admin.google.com for domain2.com and add you app for domain wide delegation for calendar service (see https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation). This has nothing to do with the domains listed in your api console. If domain2.com is not a google apps domain you can add it as secondary domain in your google apps account for domain1.com.